# Read Excel file containing file paths and create hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a macro in Outlook that reads an Excel file that has full paths and filenames in separate cells and inserts them as hyperlinks in an email.

I found information on how to create a hyperlink in Outlook. I can't find anything on how I Outlook would get the file paths from the Excel sheet.

Error says

> Compile Error: User-defined type not defined

```vb
Sub links()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ExcelFileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    ExcelFileName = "C:\links.xlsx"
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

    FilePath = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

    oMsg.TextBody = Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34)

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you post any code?  Also, have you Googled around? [This page](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) looks like a nice resource, check the "Mail Range or Selection" part.

Comment: Checked out that site but it's for sending an email using outlook from excel so it's a macro for excel, I've seen that example when I was researching. I'm trying to develop a macro for Outlook that can read from an excel file. Since I'm stuck at basically the beginning, I don't have any code but I'm fairly confident I can write the rest after I get over this first hurdle. My plan is to use a while loop to go through the rows in the excel file and use the contents of each row to create each hyperlink until I hit an empty cell.

Comment: AFAIK, VBA is used both in Excel and Outlook. Is it required that Outlook store the macro? Why couldn't you write the Macro in Excel's VB Editor, then use that to place the links in an email?  Instead of the other way around (Outlook --> Excel --> Outlook), just do Excel --> Outlook?  Especially since you'll be looping, I think I would write this from Excel.  (I could be overlooking something! Just making some suggestions/giving ideas).  The "Mail Range or Selection" looks like it'll get you 80%+ of the way there.

Comment: Ah yes, I considered doing that. The links I have in the Excel sheet are created with a VBScript. I actually only chose Excel to write the links to because I thought I'd have better luck finding how to integrate Excel in Outlook. My ideal flow for the user is VBScript (which creates the xls file) then Outlook (which reads the xls file) without ever actually interacting with Excel directly. I also thought about just writing straight to Outlook from the VBScript but having that break in between is beneficial. Also thanks for that site, I bookmarked it in case I do ever need to go the other way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Outlook VBA editor set a reference to Excel.

```
Tools | References
Tick Microsoft Excel Object Library
```

Add Option Explict to new modules. You will find this helpful.

```
Tools | Options | Editor tab
Tick Require Variable Declaration
```

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub links()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String

Dim oMsg As mailItem

ExcelFileName = "C:\links.xlsx"

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

FilePath = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

On Error Resume Next
Set oMsg = ActiveInspector.currentItem
On Error GoTo 0
If oMsg Is Nothing Then
    Set oMsg = CreateItem(0)
    oMsg.Display
End If

' This adds to existing text. 
' Must display first to save a signature
'oMsg.body = Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & oMsg.body
'or
oMsg.HTMLBody = Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & oMsg.HTMLBody

ExitRoutine:
    Set oMsg = Nothing
    Set exWb = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```